# Defaultbutton div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, defaultbutton

I am just curious; does any of you have any good javascriptresources for setting defaultbutton for all elements inside a div? I have a lot of divs that executes various javascriptfunctions and I would like all of them to have their buttons script executed when enter is pressed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I would do it is give the elements that you want to be fired a class, for example 'acceptEnter'.  Then create a handler for the containing DIVs which looks for that class on keypress.  Hope this helps :)

```
$('div').keypress( function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == '13') {
     $(this).find('.acceptEnter').click();
   }
});
```

Comment: An asp:button still fires, so I added "return false;" after click() to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a single javascript function that calls all the other scripts, and make all the buttons call this one javascript function?

Comment: Not sure how that would help.. I then would need to know which method to call in the "master" javascript that handles everything..